# Setting and getting a Global variable in Drools

Tags: drools, kie

I have something like this in drl file:

```
import java.lang.String

global String result;

rule ''Rule 1'' when some condition
    then 
result = "PASS";
kcontext.getKnowledgeRuntime().setGlobal("Result", result); // I got an "Unexpected global" exception.
System.out.println("result = "+ Result);
```

Also, I don't know how to access this global variable from my MyService.java class.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to set a global variable from the drl file not my java class like Service class.

**All I had to do was the following and it worked successfully**

import java.lang.String

global String result;

rule ''Rule 1''
when
some condition

then

```
String grade = "PASS";

kcontext.getKnowledgeRuntime().setGlobal("result", grade);
```

end

Also, the global variable name should match what I pass on the setGlobal("result",...).

And then get the global variable using the session I have in the Service class. like:

session.getGlobal("result");

Answer (score -1):

Your rule should not be touching the 'kcontext'. What in the world are you trying to do? `result = "PASS"` is sufficient for setting the value of the global.

```
global String result

rule "Rule 1" 
when 
  // some condition
then 
  result = "PASS";
end
```

Of course it's not going to work like you want it to because you need to change the value of the existing object; you can't overwrite it like that. Some options might be a "ResultsHolder" sort of class with a boolean variable you can set; or maybe even an `AtomicBoolean` that you can call set on.

To fire rules with a global, you need to add the global objects to the KieBase before invoking your rules:

```
var value = ...; // some OBJECT which you are going to pass in as a global

KieSession session = ruleBase.newStatefulSession();
session.insert(...); // insert data
session.setGlobal( "myGlobalFoo", value ); // sets the global; note the name must match the rule file!
session.fireAllRules();
```

After the rules are fired, you'll have your reference to `value` that you can use. This is also why you can't pass strings as globals and expect them to capture changes -- Java is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference.

---

Here's an example for passing results out of the rules. This toy app will check the student's score on a test and then decide if they passed or failed.

Classes:

```
class Student {
  private String name;
  public String getName() { return this.name; }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}

class Exam {
  private String name;
  private Double score;
  public String getName() { return this.name; }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
  public Double getScore() { return this.score; }
  public void setScore(String score) { this.score = score; }
}

class ExamResults {
  private List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
  public void logResults( String name, Double score, boolean passed ) {
    this.results.add(name + " scored " + score + "%, which is a " + (passed ? "passing": "failing") + " grade.");
  }
  public List<String> getResults() { return this.results; }
}
```

Rule:

```
global ExamResults results;

rule "Evaluate exam"
when
  Student( $name: name )
  Exam ( $score: score, name == $name )
then
  boolean passed = $score > 60.0;
  results.logResults( $name, $score, passed );
end
```

Invocation:

```
List<Student> students = ...;
List<Exam> exams = ... ;
ExamResults results = new ExamResults();

KieSession session = ruleBase.newStatefulSession();
students.forEach( student -> session.insert(students) );
exams.forEach( exam -> session.insert(exam) );
session.setGlobal( "results", results);
session.fireAllRules();

// Print the results:
results.getResults().forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

If all you're trying to do is to get some data out of your rules (eg whether certain conditions match), I've written up answers about how to do that previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65948928/how-to-pass-multiple-objects-in-a-drools-file-and-extract-the-desired-object/65975960/419705) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60536151/419705). If you just want to know what rules triggered, you should write a [listener](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/kie-api-javadoc/index.html?org/kie/api/event/rule/AgendaEventListener.html) which logs rule hits ("afterMatchFired").